# iPhone 6 stuck in recovery mode and need to download iOS 11 beta 1

Tags: iphone, recovery, ios

I tried to downgrade from iOS 11 beta four to 10.3.3 and my iPhone 6 is stuck in recovery mode. I read I need to restore to an earlier beta to unstick the phone but can't find good links (I am not a registered developer with Apple). How can I download the .ipsw?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an XY problem. Is there a jailbreak in play (or attempt at that) or are you unable to get signed in to the public beta portal to get the provisioning profile that activates the beta for you since you’re not a developer?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva ???? these are public betas. I am enrolled in the Apple public beta program. What is wrong with you? Your comment is factually wrong, unhelpful, and venomous.

Comment: @bmike no jailbreak in play. I was running public beta 4 and traveled to Europe. I have a T mobile plan that gives me data, texts, unlimited in 100+ countries. Arrived in Italy and my data and texts worked for a little while and then weren't working anymore. Called T mobile, but the only thing I did with the T mobile guy was toggle on and off some of the settings. At some point it started working and then stopped again. So, I thought it was a beta bug and decided to downgrade without checking what downgrading would do. That's it

Comment: @bmike what's an XY problem btw? i am signed up to the public beta portal. I went through all public betas but the betas were downloaded straight to my phone and my phone is now in recovery mode. I don't have a public beta .ispw on my laptop. That's why I am stuck. I even tried both Reiboot and Dr. Fone's software but they did not fix it

Comment: Called Apple and looks like that with 10.3.3 there shouldn't be any problem in downgrading from beta iOS 11. That's exactly what I used to downgrade, 10.3.3! So, why did it happen to me? It looks like a hardware issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to switch out of recovery mode, use ReiBoot (www.tenorshare.com/products/reiboot.html). FOr .ipsw just find any .ipsw file adequate for you iPhone though. You need to look the number of your iPhone, for instance, my iPhone is iPhone 5s, hence it is iPhone 6,2. Then Use option button when you click on restore in iTunes and it should load that .ipsw image, so THAT operating system. Again, if you get stuck in recovery mode, use ReiBoot. It saved me countless hours of retrying and restarting my iPhone.